# With maven, do I still need to configure jdb driver and datasources?

Tags: sql-server, maven, jdbc

I want to write an Java EE 6 app, on JBoss 7.1, with JPA (Hibernate  as JPA provider) and SqlServer.

The build tool is, for better or worse, Maven 3.

What does Maven arrange/set up for me in terms of connecting Jboss 7 to a database and JPA?

Do I need to set up a JDBC driver, as well as a datasource, or does Maven automagically set these up for me via transitive dependencies and its build cycle?  In other words, do I need go into standalone.xml as well as into the module folder and modify a module.xml file, etc?

I can't find a tutorial that has all of the steps or a sample pom.xml.

Comment: Maven is a build tool, creating software that runs on top of JBoss. It is not designed to manage the setup of your software infrastructure. I suspect what you're trying to do is run integration tests? Perhaps google that and you'll have more success

Answer (score 0):

No Maven will not automagically set up dependencies on JDBC providers. You must declare them explicitly in your own project pom.

As far as a tutorial, the canonical references and tutorials are on the Sonatype web site.

See: [Maven by Example](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/)

and specifically regarding project dependencies in Maven: the Complete Reference:

http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html